# How to solve "Tried emitting when not connected"

Tags: swift, sockets

"I want to use iPhone and Raspberry Pi to communicate via WiFi, transmitting IMU data from the iPhone to the Raspberry Pi, and have the Raspberry Pi print it out in real-time. However, I encountered the following issues. Here are my codes for the iPhone and Raspberry Pi sides.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gO9Zp.jpg)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/joGJU.png)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jma6a.png)

How should I resolve this?"

Comment: Post code as text and not as images. Also describe what the issue is clearly.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.